# How to call builds in parallel with delay in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build, parallel-processing

I have a Jenkins parallel build issue.  I have a large configuration options blob, and I want to call the same build job repeatedly with changes to the config blob.  I also want to delay a little bit between each run.  Also, the number of calls is based off selections so could be anywhere from 1 job to say 7 jobs at once hence building it grammatically.  Given a much paired down version of the code below assuming 'opts' are what is coming in from selection, could someone help me accomplish this.  The long job has a timestamp inside it and so we don't want them all kicking off at the exact same moment.

Without the 'sleep' I will see "Starting building: myLongJob#100", then 101, then 102 etc..  However there is no delay between the jobs.  With the sleep I see "Starting building: myLongJob #100" then 100, then 100 again.

Other than the given code, I tried adding quietPeriod: diffnum+1 but that either did nothing or waited until the long job finished.  I also tried adding wait: true (and wait: false).  Still I see no delay or the same job build number repeatedly.

```
cfgOtps = """
    server: MYOPTION
    prefix: Testing
"""

def opts = ["Windows", "Linux", "Mac"]
// function will create a list of cfg blobs with server replaced by 'opt' so in this example
// cfgs will be length of 3 with server beign Windows, Linux, and Mac respectively
def cfgs = generate_cfg_list(cfgOtps, opts)

//update so each entry in branches has a different key
def branchnum = 0  
def branches = [:]
//variable to have different inside the closure
def diffnum = -1
def runco = ""
cfgs.each {
    branchnum += 1
    branches["branch${branchnum}"] = {
            diffnum += 1
            //sleep(diffnum+5)

            def deployResult = build job: 'myLongJob', parameters: [[$class: 'TextParameterValue', name: 'ConfigObj', value: cfgs[diffnum]],
                                                                            string(name:'dummy', value: "${diffnum}")]
        }

}
parallel branches
```

I expected the output to be something like the following with a short delay between them.

```
Starting building: myLongJob #100
Starting building: myLongJob #101
Starting building: myLongJob #102
```

Which I do get if I do not have the sleep.  The issue there is the long job needs to not be run at the same time so sometimes overwrites things.
Adding the sleep results in the following

```
Starting building: myLongJob #100
Starting building: myLongJob #100
Starting building: myLongJob #100
```

or maybe 2 with the same number and one a different build number.  Not sure why a sleep would induce that behavior?

Comment: You can not delay the trigger of a parallel job, you can delay some operation in those. But i dont understand why this can be needed, can you enlight be on the reasoning? If your real goal is, to not use a resource at the same time, there are better ways to achieve this beside some sleep or delay. Edit: Conceptionally, what issue makes you to think you need a delay there?

Comment: Dominik, The issue is the subsequent job (myLongJob in this case) creates information based on the start of the job's timestamp.  I can not have them kicked off at the exact same time or they will all use the same output.  I can't modify myLogJob as it is not in my domain, so stuck with it using the timestamp to label some info.  Kicking all off in parallel will have them all stomp on each other, while waiting at least 2 seconds between will not.

Comment: I see, concenptionally the problem is using the timestamp as differentiator. Since you cannot change the long job, i think your only way is to sneak in some parameterized proxy job which you call with a sleep duration parameter different for each parallel execution, it sleeps for that duration and then calls `myLongJob` and wait till its finished. This is not very elegant, but seems the only solution regarding these constraints.

Comment: Thanks!  I will give that a shot!